# How to do diagonal flip animation in android?

Tags: android, matrix, android-animation

```
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0">
</scale>

<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="45">
</rotate>
```

Using these I am not able to do diagonal flip. Is there any way to do this flip.

I have tried with `matrix.setskew` but I don't know how to work on matrix.

Comment: whats wrong? i tried your code and it works

Comment: Its a simple flip but i need a diagonal flip ...

Answer (score 0):

Try with an Object animator. If you want to read about object animator have a look at the following link. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html

And for horizontal flip create an `xml` file under animator directory in resources with the folowing code.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="900"
    android:propertyName="rotationY"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="90"
    android:id="@+id/anim1">
</objectAnimator>

<objectAnimator
    android:duration="900"
    android:propertyName="rotationY"
    android:valueFrom="90"
    android:valueTo="0" >
</objectAnimator>
```

And you can call this animation on any view using the below code. **R.animator.flip** is the name of your xml.

```
AnimatorSet mAnimation = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, R.animator.flip);

mAnimation.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
       //what you want to do on animation start
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
      //what you want to do on animation ended
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        //what you want to do on animation canceled
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        //what you want to do on animation repeated
    }
});
```

This gives you a lot of control on what you want to do.

You start the animation with

```
mAnimation.setTarget(<the view you want to target>);
mAnimation.start();
```

The listener is optional, if you do not need any control over your animation and just want it to execute your xml then you can create only the xml file and use the above two lines.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for some time, too. It would be easy by specifying a 4x4 transformation matrix and computing it for every frame, but unfortunately there is only a 3x3 matrix object in Android, which doesn't support 3D rotation and translation. My solution for flipping around both diagonals:

```
public class RightDiagonalFlipAnimation extends Animation {
        private float fromDegree;
        private float toDegree;
        private float densityDpi;

        private float width;
        private Camera camera;

        public RightDiagonalFlipAnimation(float fromDegree, float toDegree, float densityDpi) {
            this.fromDegree = fromDegree;
            this.toDegree = toDegree;
            this.densityDpi = densityDpi;
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
            super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
            this.width = width;
            camera = new Camera();

            float cameraDistance = width * 25;
            camera.setLocation(0, 0, -cameraDistance/densityDpi);
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            float xDegrees = fromDegree + ((toDegree - fromDegree) * interpolatedTime);
            final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();

            camera.save();
            camera.rotateX(-xDegrees);
            camera.getMatrix(matrix);
            camera.restore();

            matrix.preTranslate(-this.width/(float) Math.sqrt(2), -this.width/(float) Math.sqrt(2));
            matrix.postTranslate(this.width/(float)Math.sqrt(2), this.width/(float)Math.sqrt(2));
            matrix.postRotate(-45);
            matrix.preRotate(45);
        }
    }

public class LeftDiagonalFlipAnimation extends Animation {
        private float fromDegree;
        private float toDegree;
        private float densityDpi;

        private float width;
        private Camera camera;

        public LeftDiagonalFlipAnimation(float fromDegree, float toDegree, float densityDpi) {
            this.fromDegree = fromDegree;
            this.toDegree = toDegree;
            this.densityDpi = densityDpi;
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
            super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
            this.width = width;
            camera = new Camera();

            float cameraDistance = width * 25;
            camera.setLocation(0, 0, -cameraDistance/densityDpi);
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            float xDegrees = fromDegree + ((toDegree - fromDegree) * interpolatedTime);
            final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();

            camera.save();
            camera.rotateX(xDegrees);
            camera.getMatrix(matrix);
            camera.restore();

            matrix.postRotate(45);
            matrix.preRotate(-45);
        }
    }
```